# Creating a string from a Php array and writing it to a text file

Tags: php, file, implode

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => firstname1,
    [1] => lastname1,
    [2] => firstname2,
    [3] => lastname2,
    [4] => firstname3,
    [5] => lastname3
)
```

Now I want to create a text file containing this content:

```
firstname1|lastname1#firstname2|lastname2#firstname3|lastname3#
```

How can I do that?

Comment: you can at least show us what you tried, if you did.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I just want to know, how can I create a `.txt` file using *PHP*. Just that, I will create a regex of my array later

Comment: What relevance is the `#` ? And as mentioned by @Fred-ii- what have you tried so far? What didnt work?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: You should check out `file_put_contents()` for file creation and insertion and `implode()` to convert the array into a string. http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: Google'd (for you) *"how to create a .txt file with php"* - http://stackoverflow.com/q/9265274/ and http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filecreate.php and http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filewrite.php and http://stackoverflow.com/q/14998961/ amongst many others.

Comment: Thanks everybody ...

Comment: *hah!* someone even put in an answer using the links from above, *rich!* - Had I known, I'd of done the same ;-) but I'm not like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the array in pairs, contcatenating with your chosen characters, to build a string, and then write it to a file with [file_put_contents](https://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

```
<?php
$names = array(
    'firstname1',
    'lastname1',
    'firstname2',
    'lastname2',
    'firstname3',
    'lastname3'
);

for(
    $i = 0, $n = count($names), $str = '';
    $i < $n;
    $i += 2
)
{
    $str .= $names[$i] . '|' . $names[$i+1] . '#';
}
file_put_contents('/tmp/names.txt', $str);
```

Or to build the string we could chunk the original array into pairs:

```
$str = '';
foreach(array_chunk($names, 2) as list($first, $second))
    $str .= $first . '|' . $second . '#';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array(
    'firstname1',
    'lastname1',
    'firstname2',
    'lastname2',
    'firstname3',
    'lastname3'
);
$str = implode('@', $array) . '@';
$str = preg_replace('/(.+?)@(.+?)@/', '$1|$2#', $str);
file_put_contents('/tmp/file.txt', $str);
```

Edit inspired by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16687155/3392762, and what came before.

Comment: This is about the only answer (so far) that makes any sense.

Comment: it isn't actually right as i didn't read the output correctly which is my fault. I'll edit it shortly

Comment: No problemo. I wasn't criticizing it, do what you can ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have a question of *You*, you know the answer ... is it not? So why you don't write an answer under my question? really why?

Comment: @stack so I'm the one who gets "shot at", *sigh*. Double rich.

Comment: @stack by the way, that answer just here, isn't the one I was referring too, I was referring to this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/34324050/ at least this guy `user3697474` made an "effort".

Comment: progrock has the right answer. You need to loop through the array and create a string which can be then parsed into a text file. There's no need to edit my answer when one is available.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes I did what I needed according to your links...! But still I believe you are a weird person ..! Also I like your avatar ;-)

Comment: Thanks @user3697474 +1