# Replacing all latex occurences $$ ... $$ to inline \( ... \) by modifying the string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

I have tried a couple of solutions regarding "replace second occurence in a string" (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16686963/1066234)) but could not get the solution for my problem.

String example:

`$string = "$$ f'(x) = 12x^2 + 4x $$  $$ f'(x) = 12x+2x-12 $$  $$ f'(x) = 12x^3 +4x^2 $$";`

Goal:

`$string = "\( f'(x) = 12x^2 + 4x \) \( f'(x) = 12x+2x-12 \) \( f'(x) = 12x^3 +4x^2 \)";`

I found this [gist snippet](https://gist.github.com/VijayaSankarN/0d180a09130424f3af97b17d276b72bd#file-str_replace_n-php):

```
function str_replace_n($search, $replace, $subject, $occurrence)
{
    $search = preg_quote($search);
    return preg_replace("/^((?:(?:.*?$search){".--$occurrence."}.*?))$search/", "$1$replace", $subject);
}
```

And tried to carefully call it on the second instance by:

`$string = str_replace_n('$$', '\)', $string, 2);`

So that I can then go over the remaining `$$` and replace them by `\(`.

However, the function does nothing when I call it like that.

I thought it is an escape issue since `$$` are rexeg operators, but even escaping them did not change the outcome (the preg_quote in the function should do the magic, I assume): `$string = str_replace_n('\$\$', '\\)', $string, 2);` - nope …

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search using this regex:

```
\$\$((?:(?!\$\$).)*)\$\$
```

and replace using:

```
\\($1\\)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9J4OWw/1)

Lookahead expression `(?:(?!\$\$).)` matches any character that is not a `$$`

**Code:**

```
$re = '/\$\$((?:(?!\$\$).)*)\$\$/';
$str = '$$ f\'(x) = 12x^2 + 4x $$  $$ f\'(x) = 12x+2x-12 $$  $$ f\'(x) = 12x^3 +4x^2 $$';
$subst = '\\\\($1\\\\)';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

As @Wiktor suggested below a simple non-greedy regex pattern will also work here:

```
\$\$(.*?)\$\$
```

Comment: Did you just answer within 60 seconds after I have asked?! ... and it works... hallelujah, outstanding.

Comment: It is much easier to use `\$\$(.*?)\$\$`. Using a tempered greedy token here is not justified.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Yes right, in this case `\$\$(.*?)\$\$` will also work

Comment: Anyway, the most efficient pattern variation for this approach will be [`\$\$([^$]*(?:\$(?!\$)[^$]*)*)\$\$`](https://regex101.com/r/GCoQcS/1).

Comment: Feel free to add it as an answer or we are going to see this comment section overfilled. @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**: [`\${2}([^$]+)\${2}`](https://regex101.com/r/qRMJVT/1) or `\${2}(.+?)\${2}` **Substitution**: `($1)`

Details:

- `{n}` Matches exactly `n` times
- `[^]` Match a single character not present in the list
- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times

**PHP code**:

```
$string = "$$ f'(x) = 12x^2 + 4x $$  $$ f'(x) = 12x+2x-12 $$  $$ f'(x) = 12x^3 +4x^2 $$";

$string = preg_replace('~\${2}([^$]+)\${2}~', '($1)', $string);
print_r($string);
```

Output:

```
( f'(x) = 12x^2 + 4x )  ( f'(x) = 12x+2x-12 )  ( f'(x) = 12x^3 +4x^2 )
```